# Tkinter image saying file does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have some code and am trying to display an image into a window. When I run this script, it says the file does not exist when it is in the same file.

```
#poker table
root=Tk()
root.config(bg='#1b800b')
root.title('PokerChamp')
root.withdraw()

photo = PhotoImage('table.png')

label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.image = photo 
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Also, that's not full traceback.

Comment: For what reason do you need `root.withdraw()`?

Comment: I’m making a separate window that opens before root and closes to open the root window

Comment: Should be `photo = PhotoImage(file='table.png')`.

Comment: I have resolved the issue now, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not certain what your root directory is use this snippet of code:

```
print(os.path.relpath(__file__))
```

If the path is for example "py\script.py" and the image you have is in the py folder as well, then you have to use the path with the py folder name: PhotoImage('py\table.png')

Edit: You have to import os as well:

```
import os
```